# Limit of number of checks in a PHP If statement

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and HTML I have several other IF statements with two or three OR in it and they seem to work just fine.

What I'm checking for is 'NULL', 'blank', 'space' or text 'None'.  If I find any of these I want to do the select statement.  If no matches I would like to use the $AT_Med_1_1 data which has been pull out of a database.

IF statement as shown below which does not see me to work.  It always drops into the SELECT statement even when $AT_Med_1_1 is something else.

```
       if ($AT_Med_1_1 == '' or $AT_Med_1_1 == NULL or $AT_Med_1_1 == ' ' or    $AT_Med_1_1 = 'None') {
 <select name="AT_Med_1_2">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Oral_Zofran">Oral Zofran</option>
        <option value="IV_Zofran">IV_Zofran</option>
        <option value="Oxygen">Oxygen</option>
        <option value="Ibuprofen">Ibuprofen</option>
        <option value="Aetaminothen">Aetaminothen</option>
        <option value="Upinephrne">Upinephrne</option>
        <option value="Xopenex">Xopenex</option>
        <option value="Albuterol">Albuterol</option>
        <option value="Valium">Valium</option>
        <option value="Magnesiunsulphate">Magnesiunsulphate</option>
        <option value="Diphenhyamine">Diphenhyamine</option>
        <option value="Ketorolac">Ketorolac</option>
        <option value="Promethazion">Promethazion</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Soup">Oral Fluids Soup</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Electrolyte">Oral Fluids Electrolyte</option>
        <option value="Oral_Fluids_Water">Oral Fluids Water</option>        
      </select>
      <?php
      }  else {
//          echo 'Showing $AT_';
          echo $AT_Med_1_2;
          echo nl2br("\n");
      }
?>
```

If I change the IF statement to several elseif it seem to work correctly

```
if ($AT_Med_1_1 == '')      
{
   goto test1;
 } else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == NULL)
{
   goto test1;
} else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == ' ')
{
   goto test1;
 } else if ($AT_Med_1_1 == 'None')
{
   goto test1;
 }
    goto test;  

    test1:         
              ?>
          <select name="AT_Med_1_1">
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="Oral_Zofran">Oral Zofran</option>
            <option value="IV_Zofran">IV_Zofran</option>
            <option value="Oxygen">Oxygen</option>
            <option value="Ibuprofen">Ibuprofen</option>
            <option value="Aetaminothen">Aetaminothen</option>
            <option value="Upinephrne">Upinephrne</option>
            <option value="Xopenex">Xopenex</option>
            <option value="Albuterol">Albuterol</option>
            <option value="Valium">Valium</option>
            <option value="Magnesiunsulphate">Magnesiunsulphate</option>
            <option value="Diphenhyamine">Diphenhyamine</option>
            <option value="Ketorolac">Ketorolac</option>
            <option value="Promethazion">Promethazion</option>
            <option value="Oral_Fluids_Soup">Oral Fluids Soup</option>
            <option value="Oral_Fluids_Electrolyte">Oral Fluids Electrolyte</option>
            <option value="Oral_Fluids_Water">Oral Fluids Water</option>        
          </select>
              <?php
              goto endtest;

    test: 
              echo $AT_Med_1_1;
              echo nl2br("\n");
    endtest:
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (... or $AT_Med_1_1 = 'None') {
```

For the last condition you accidentally wrote `=` instead of `==`.